# Django: How to return an inline formset with errors

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, modelform

I have created a form to sign up a user by having them create a User object and a UserProfile object as follows:

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email",)

class UserProfileCreationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
        )

RegisteredCustomerProfileCreationInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    User,
    UserProfile,
    form=UserProfileCreationForm,
    extra=1,
    can_delete=False,
    can_order=False,
)
```

In my view to display the sign up form, I do the following:

```
class UserSignupView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = "users/signup_form.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Adds the inline formset to the context."""
        context = super(UserSignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            context[
                "user_profile_inline"
            ] = UserProfileCreationInlineFormset(
                self.request.POST
            )
        else:
            context[
                "user_profile_inline"
            ] = UserProfileCreationInlineFormset()
        return context

    def form_invalid(self, request, form):
        # Note: I added request as an argument because I was getting an error that
        # says the method is expecting 2 arguments but got 3.
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, 
            self.get_context_data(
                form=form
            )
        )

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        user_profile_inline = context["user_profile_inline"]

        if (
            form.is_valid()
            and user_profile_inline.is_valid()
        ):
            # Handle valid case
            ...
            return redirect(
                self.request.GET.get(reverse_lazy("index"))
            )

        else:
            self.form_invalid(self, form)
```

My template is as simple as

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ user_profile_inline.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="Save">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

When my `form` which is for creation of the User object is invalid, the template is reloaded nicely with the errors in the form. However, when the formset is invalid, I get the error: "didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Please may you assist me with the correct way of reloading the template with errors for the inline formset.

Comment: Unless it's been clipped off, you are not returning anything in your `form_valid` method

Comment: @Lewis Thanks for the response. I've now added the return line for the case when the forms are valid. If they are invalid, it goes to the form_invalid method which I'm most concerned with. I want it to re-render the template but with the errors in the inline formset displayed on the template. This works when there are errors in the User form but doesn't work when there are errors in the inline formset.

Comment: The ```else``` path in your ```form_valid``` method is still not returning anything

Comment: Ahhhhh I see. I thought return render in the form_invalid method was going to be enough to trigger the reload. Ok now I'm returning self.form_invalid() and it works. Just realised I need to write something to handle a case when the inline formset is completely blank and is not even validated; it seems to go down the valid route. Thanks so much.

Comment: How to solve this in function view?

Answer (score 0):

For me I had a Function Based View.

If your code looks something like this:

***views.py***

```
def fbv(request, model_slug):
    modelName = ModelName.objects.get(slug=model_slug)

    ModelName2Formset = inlineformset_factory(
                    ModelName, ModelName2, fields=('field1', 'field2',), 
                    extra=3, 
                    can_delete = True,
                    widgets={
                        'field1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text here'}),
                        'field2': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Numbers here'}),
                        },
                    )

    if request.method == "POST":
    
        formset = ModelName2Formset(request.POST, instance=modelName)
        
        
        if formset.is_valid():
            
            formset.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('url-name')
        

    
    formset = ModelName2Formset(instance=modelName)

    return render(request, 'AppName/add-modelName2.html', {'formset' : formset, 'modelName': modelName})
```

---

What I did was to add an else to the `if request.method == "POST":`

***views.py***

```
def fbv(request, model_slug):

    ...

    if request.method == "POST":
    
        formset = ModelName2Formset(request.POST, instance=modelName)
        
        
        if formset.is_valid():
            
            formset.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('url-name')
        

    # I added else here
    else:
        formset = ModelName2Formset(instance=modelName)
```